# Client Side doesn't send texts to server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am currently making a simple chat application using java sockets between two android devices 
my problem is the client connect to the server after I enter the IP address and port perfectly 
then when I try to send any text from client to server the client side suddenly stop I searched a lot but I couldn't find what it's wrong with my code

Server Side :

```
Thread TH=new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    status.setText("hosted on"+ ip);
                    ss=new ServerSocket(8080);
                    while(true) {
                        S = ss.accept();

                        status.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            status.setText("connected");
                                        }
                                    }
                        );
                        CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(S);
                        new Thread(commThread).start();

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
        private Socket ClientSocket;
        DataInputStream DIS;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket ClientSocket) throws IOException {
            this.ClientSocket = ClientSocket;

            DIS = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
            data = DIS.readUTF();
        }
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                data = data.toString();
                tv_receive.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        tv_receive.setText(data);
                    }
```

Client Side :

```
 btn_connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TH=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            S = new Socket(et_IP_Address.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(et_port.getText().toString()));
                            DOS = new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });// End of thread
                TH.start();
            }
        }); // end of  buutton

        // Sending
        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TH=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //while(true) {

                            DOS.write(Integer.parseInt(et_message.getText().toString()));
                            tv_transmit.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    tv_transmit.setText(et_message.getText());

                                }
                            });
                            try {
                                DOS.flush();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // }
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            DOS.close();

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

that what i get after the client crash ::

```
03-16 10:55:09.434 5521-5521/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-16 10:55:09.554 5521-5521/app.droid.moring E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 232: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 235: Landroid/app/Application;.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is app.droid.moring, real application class is null.
03-16 10:55:09.804 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
03-16 10:55:09.824 5521-5521/app.droid.moring E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
03-16 10:55:09.824 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1901 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
03-16 10:55:09.824 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x025e
03-16 10:55:09.824 5521-5521/app.droid.moring E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
03-16 10:55:09.824 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1901 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
03-16 10:55:09.824 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0060
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16095: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16097: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16101: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 681: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 703: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-16 10:55:09.874 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
03-16 10:55:09.904 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
03-16 10:55:09.904 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16529: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-16 10:55:09.904 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.904 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
03-16 10:55:09.904 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
03-16 10:55:09.904 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-16 10:55:09.914 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-16 10:55:09.914 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 644: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-16 10:55:09.914 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.914 5521-5521/app.droid.moring I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-16 10:55:09.914 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 646: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-16 10:55:09.914 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-16 10:55:09.924 5521-5521/app.droid.moring E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
03-16 10:55:09.924 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 151 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
03-16 10:55:09.924 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
03-16 10:55:09.964 5521-5524/app.droid.moring D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 211K, 10% free 2590K/2860K, paused 5ms+14ms, total 25ms
03-16 10:55:10.154 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-16 10:55:10.154 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-16 10:55:10.174 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

                                                        [ 03-16 10:55:10.174  5521: 5521 D/         ]
                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb84e6710, tid 5521
03-16 10:55:10.314 5521-5521/app.droid.moring W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed
03-16 10:55:10.364 5521-5521/app.droid.moring D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-16 10:55:32.854 5521-5884/app.droid.moring W/dalvikvm: threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0ff2908)
03-16 10:55:32.854 5521-5884/app.droid.moring E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-211
                                                                java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "hi"
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
                                                                    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
                                                                    at app.droid.moring.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:75)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: suddenly stop usually means crash, and crash always comes with an exception, post the stacktrace error you get in logcat

Comment: `data = DIS.readUTF();`. Not there! Put it in the following while loop.

Comment: If you want the server to use readUTF then your client should use writeUTF.

Comment: @greenapps thank u i fixed it and used writeUTF but it still crash

Comment: `suddenly stop usually means crash, and crash always comes with an exception, post the stacktrace error you get in logcat `. Well you heard what you have to dol.

Comment: @Yazan thank you,, i did

Comment: Well it is pretty clear what you do wrong. You can read it in your posted log: `FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-211
                                                                java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "hi"`. You understand now? You now realize which code line causes this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse a String as Integer, while it's not numeric

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "hi"

this could be this line

```
Integer.parseInt(et_port.getText().toString())
```

or this

```
DOS.write(Integer.parseInt(et_message.getText().toString()));
```

it's on Mainactivity line 75

So, either remove the `Integer.parseInt()` call, or enter a valid numeric integer value

Comment: @NoranMagdi ahlan Noran, el 3afo :)